# How to send base64 string in a url?

Tags: c#, wcf, url, base64

I have an ionic app through which, i want to send a base64 string to my WCF service. As the base64 string is huge, i'm getting the following error- "**HTTP Error 414. The request URL is too long.**" I have hosted this service on IIS. Is there any way to get this working? I tried searching this issue online but didn't get any way.

this is my method -

```
 [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",UriTemplate = "/ReportaBug?base64String={base64String}", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json )]
        void ReportaBug(string base64String);
```

and this is my web.config file -

```
 <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1" />
    <httpRuntime  targetFramework="4.6.2" maxUrlLength="32768" maxQueryStringLength="32768"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="web">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" minFreeMemoryPercentageToActivateService="0"/>
    <services>
      <service name="FusionRestService.FusionRestService" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
        <endpoint binding="webHttpBinding" contract="FusionRestService.IFusionRestService" behaviorConfiguration="web"></endpoint>
        <endpoint
            address="mex"
            binding="mexHttpBinding"
            contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
         <requestLimits maxQueryString="32768"/>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
```

Comment: Transmit your data in Body, not URL. The URL has a maximum length - Period. We have to deal with that. The obvious thing is to transmit data in the message body (where it belongs).

Comment: How to send the data in message body? Could you please show some sample code or references?

Comment: It's been a while, but if I remember correctly, you just need to get rid of the parameter in the uriTemplate. Not sure if you need to use a Stream as type for the method param and read it, or if it "just works" ... Maybe you need to use another BodyStyle than Bare (pretty sure, in fact).

Comment: [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",UriTemplate = "/ReportaBug, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json )]
        void ReportaBug(string base64String);

is this what you're talking about?

Comment: I think, yes. I haven't been working in WCF for quite a while, so I'd have to experiment, too. But to me, it's looking fine.

Comment: I tried this but it isn't working. still shows the request too long error

Comment: Of course, you'll have to fix the sender side, also. It needs to but that string into the body now. But I guess, you did that, right?

Comment: Yes. i did that.  Still can't get it working.

Comment: Do you have some tool to sniff your network packets? I think you'll need to check, what's on the line actually. Something like Fiddler or Wireshark?

Answer (score 0):

this is an IIS error telling you the length of the given URL exceeds a limit. IIS’ maximum URL length is defined by the `HttpRuntimeSection.MaxUrlLength` property. Its value is 260 characters. This may cause problems with longer than configured `maxUrlLength` URL’s, and here is how to resolve this issue:
https://www.saotn.org/the-length-url-request-exceeds-configured-maxurllength-value/

***UPDATE***
I tested your code in my localhost and its working just fine. i just added this parameters in my `web.config`

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.2" maxUrlLength="32768" maxQueryStringLength="32768" />
```

and

```
<security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxQueryString="32768"/>
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

Comment: I changed the maxURLlength, still i'm getting the same error - HTTP Error 414. The request URL is too long.

Comment: where is your web server? do you access it via Internet or public network? sometimes routers block the unusual traffics.

Comment: It is in the shared network. I have hosted the service on IIS.

Comment: i tested your code with 300 characters in url and it works just fine.

Comment: Yeah. 300 characters works fine. The base64 string which i'm sending is of 25824 characters.

Comment: can you host your application on your local hsot?

Comment: Sure. Thanks!
I hosted it on local host too but same error

Comment: I tried this but i'm still getting the same error. I've updated my web.config file in the question. What is going wrong ? i've tried everything.